# Template methods calling each other in C++

Tags: c++, templates

I've got 2 classes with methods that call each other. One of them is a template method:

```
// Foo.h
class Foo {
public:
    void foo_method() {
        Bar::bar_method();
    }

    template <typename U>
    static void foo_other_method() {
        // some code
    }
};

// Bar.h
class Bar {
public:
    static void bar_method() {
        Foo::foo_other_method<int>();
    }
};
```

And I call it like this:

```
Foo f;
f.foo_method();
```

How should I arrange the `#include` directives in `Foo.h` and `Bar.h` so this code compiles?

Comment: Move the non-template function definitions into a .cpp source file.

Comment: Don't define the function inline inside the classes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the implementation of `Foo::foo_method()` so that the definition of `Bar` is available.

Since it is not a function template, you can move it to a .cpp file.

Foo.h:

```
#pragma once
class Foo {
public:
    void foo_method();

    template <typename U>
    static void foo_other_method() {
        // some code
    }
};
```

Bar.h:

```
#pragma once
// Need this so Foo::foo_other_method() can be used.
#include "Foo.h"
class Bar {
public:
    static void bar_method() {
        Foo::foo_other_method<int>();
    }
};
```

Foo.cpp:

```
#include "Foo.h"
#include "Bar.h"

void Foo::foo_method()
{
   Bar::bar_method();
}
```